# Changing Array elements by call by value

Tags: c++, arrays, call-by-value

I am passing array elements to a function. This function adds 5 to each element of the array. I am also passing an integer and adding 5 to it... Even though it is a 'call by value' function the value of the integer dosn't change in `main()` (which is expected) but the array elements do change...

I wan't to know how and why?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void change(int x[],int y);

int main()
{
    int sharan[]={1,2,3,4};
    int a=10;
    change(sharan,a);
    for(int j=0;j<4;j++)
    {
        cout<<sharan[j]<<endl;
    }
    cout<<endl<<"a is : "<<a;
    return(0);
}

void change(int x[],int y)
{
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        x[i]+=5;
    }
    y+=5;
}
```

Comment: You need a pointer to change the value of the variable

Comment: passing integer a and then adding 5 to y!!!!!!!

Comment: When you call `change(sharan,a)` a copy of the value of a is made and used inside the function. (The function assigns 5 to that copy which is fine but has nothing to do with the outside `a` which stays unaffected.) Declare the parameter `y` as a reference like this: `void change(int x[],int &y){ ... }`. Then y will become an alias for (not a copy of) of a and changes to y will be equivalent to changes of a.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Array decays to pointer,

`void change(int x[],int y)` is equivalent to `void change (int *x, int y )`

with `x[i] += 5;`

you're changing the content of address at `x+i`

`y=5;` inside `change` basically updates a local copy of `y` whose address wasn't passed, hence no modification in actual value of `y` after `change` exists

Answer (score 1):

since `array` is always a reference type so any changes outside  will affect the `array` in calling function too.

As you can see in your code :

```
change(sharan,a); // here `sharan` points the base address an you are passing it.
```

Comment: @PaulR it is `Address`

Answer (score 1):

C++ does not support passing raw arrays by value. When you try to pass them as such they are converted into a pointer to the array. For this reason if you modify the elements of the array then the change will be reflected in the calling function. In this case `main()`.